# XSLT 1.0 word count with HTML

Tags: html, xslt, recursion, count, cpu-word

I am looking to call a template that will trim down a field to 30 words.  However, this field contains HTML and the HTML should not count as a word.

Comment: You're for sure restricted to 1.0?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. fn:tokenize() in 2.0 works awesome for stuff like that. I'm sure Dimitre, Tomalak or Alejandro will post a good 1.0 answer (from which I will take notes). +1 for a good question

Comment: I'm very sorry myself. I soooo wish our platform had 2.0.

Comment: @Randy< This is a very good question, +1. I will be coming with a solution but for this serious problem I will need some time, so be patient. :)

Comment: Is your html being treated as part of the xml document, or as text content within an xml node? i.e., do you have `<field>&lt;i&gt; etc..` in your xml, or `<field><i>etc..`?

Comment: @Randy: If your contained HTML is just text encode like Flynn1179 example (`field>&lt;i&gt;` instead of `<field><i>`) then you should need an XSLT implementation of XML parser (I think I may need more than just "some time". I don't know about Dimitre...) or a non standar solution (with RTF plus `node-set()`, maybe). Otherwise, the solution would be very simple.

Comment: @Alejandro: It's not quite that bad, the HTML tags can be left intact, so don't really need to parse them, just make sure that whenever you see a &lt;, you copy everything up to the next &gt; as is. I've already added a solution which does this.

Comment: @Flynn1179: `just make sure that whenever you see a &lt;, you copy everything up to the next &gt; as is`. Well, that would be a minimal parser implementation!

Comment: @Flynn1179: And, by the way, that parser would break  `<field>&lt;i&gt; This &lt; is less than sign!&lt;i&gt;<field>`

Comment: Strictly speaking that's true, but only if the html wasn't valid anyway. `<i>This < is less than sign</i>` isn't valid.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I don't want to argue, but if it is encode it would be valid HTML. The input (not provided) should be such this `<i>This &lt; is less than sign</i>` will be encode as `&lt;i&gt; This &amp;lt; is less than sign!&lt;i&gt;`. But then, maybe if needed, you would need to add entity decode...

Comment: By the way, XPath 2.1 WD have added `fn:parse`. Also, I have tested my idea of building a RTF with DOE and then ussing a `node-set` extension fuction. I didn't work...

Comment: @Randy, @Alejandro: I thought that the XHTML document is already parsed. If @randy could confirm that the whole document is just represented by a string, then NO, this isn't something to be done by XSLT -- in fact, XSLT works on trees as primary input, not on a string of characters, representing a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, although admittedly the translate call's a bit ugly:

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-length(translate(normalize-space(.),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',''))+1" />
</xsl:template>
```

This of course requires that the string in the translate call includes all characters that could appear in the field, other than spaces. It works by first calling `normalize-space(.)` to strip out both double-spaces and all but the text content. It then removes everything except spaces, counts the length of the resulting string and adds one. It does mean if you have `<p>My<b>text</b> test</p>` this will count as 2, as it will consider `Mytext` to be one word.

If you need a more robust solution, it's a little more convoluted:

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="countwords">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$count + 1" /></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This passes the result of `normalize-space(.)` into a recursive named template that calls itself when there's a space in `$text`, incrementing it's `count` parameter, and chopping off the first word each time using the `substring-after($text,' ')` call. If there's no space, then it treats `$text` as a single word, and just returns `$count + 1` (+1 for the current word).

Bear in mind that this will include ALL text content within the field, including those within inner elements.

EDIT: Note to self: read the question properly, just noticed you needed more than just a word count. That's significantly more complicated to do if you want to include any xml tags, but a slight modification of the above is all it takes to spit out each word rather than simply count them:

```
<xsl:template name="countwords">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count = 30" />
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,' ')">
      <xsl:if test="$count != 0"><xsl:text>&#32;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,' ')" />
      <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$text" /></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

There's an extra `<xsl:when` clause to simply stop recursing when count hits 30, and the recursive clause outputs the text, after adding a space at the beginning if it wasn't the first word.

EDIT: Ok, here's a solution that keeps the escaped XML content:

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="countwords">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with($text, '&lt;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,'&gt;'),'&gt;')" />
      <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
        <xsl:with-param name="count">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(substring-after($text,'&gt;'),' ')"><xsl:value-of select="$count + 1" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$count" /></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&gt;')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="(contains($text, '&lt;') and contains($text, ' ') and string-length(substring-before($text,' ')) &lt; string-length(substring-before($text,'&lt;'))) or (contains($text,' ') and not(contains($text,'&lt;')))">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 29"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text, ' '),'&#32;')" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$count = 29"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ' ')" /></xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
        <xsl:with-param name="count">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(substring-before($text, ' ')) = ''"><xsl:value-of select="$count" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$count + 1" /></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="(contains($text, '&lt;') and contains($text, ' ') and string-length(substring-before($text,' ')) &gt; string-length(substring-before($text,'&lt;'))) or contains($text,'&lt;')">
      <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 30">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:call-template name="countwords">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat('&lt;',substring-after($text,'&lt;'))" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 30">
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

If you need any of it explained better, let me know, I'd rather not go into detail unless you need it!

Comment: The major problem with the first proposed solution is that it will only recognize words in the Latin alphabet and non-words, such as "3X2". The major problem with the second proposed solution is that it will count strings such: "word,word", "word:word", "word.word", "word;word", ..., etc as single words.

Comment: Another issue is that strings like "---------------", "_______________", "===========", etc. will be counted as words.

Comment: I believe I quite clearly made that point when I said 'This of course requires that the string in the translate call includes all characters that could appear in the field'.

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions do not account for spaces within the HTML:    <i style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; font-size:11px;">How We Adapt to Change will Determine Our Success</i><br />
              <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:11px;">Simplify reimbursement issues with a resource that guides users on their path to choose the right plan for them.  Click here to find out more information and sign up for updates</span>

Comment: As far as counting things like "word,word" as two separate words, you've got two choices: either replace `normalize-space(.)` with `normalize-space(translate(., ',:;.', ' '))`, or add a separate `<xsl:when>` clause in the template for each separator. To be honest though, if you want this level of parsing, I wouldn't recommend doing it with xpath/xslt.

Comment: @Randy: This solution disregards the html markup altogether; isn't that what you meant when you said the HTML should not count as a word? At what point in the above example would you expect a solution to truncate?

Comment: <i style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; font-size:11px;">How We Adapt to Change will Determine Our Success</i><br />  <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:11px;">Simplify reimbursement issues with a resource that guides users on their path to choose the right plan for them. Click here

Comment: It would be great if it could also include any closing html tags, so in the above examble - 

  
<i style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; font-size:11px;">How We Adapt to Change will Determine Our Success</i><br /> <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:11px;">Simplify reimbursement issues with a resource that guides users on their path to choose the right plan for them. Click here</span>

Comment: Ah, ok.. my solution will just give you 'How We Adapt to Change will Determine Our Success Simplify reimbursement issues with a resource that guides users on their path to choose the right plan for them. Click here' as an output. It's possible to adapt that template to 'skip over' the html stuff, but I would need to know if your html is escaped as textual content of an xml element or not though.

Comment: no its not escaped, 

&lt;i style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; font-size:11px;"&gt;How We Adapt to Change will Determine Our Success&lt;/i&gt;&lt;br /&gt;  &lt;span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:2px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:11px;"&gt;Simplify reimbursement issues with a resource that guides users on their path to choose the right plan for them. Click here to find out more information and sign up for updates&lt;/span&gt;

Comment: @Flynn1179: You just gradually realize how far you are even from complete understanding of the problem Randy has defined -- you still haven't realized some significant problems -- you still don't see them at all. It would be good to consider deleting your answer.

Comment: As it was perhaps it wasn't an adequate solution, but that's not a sufficient reason to delete it; the ability to do a word count may be useful to other readers. However, now that the question's been clarified a little, I've added a solution which seems to work as intended.

Comment: @Flynn1179: your solution is very far from what was asked for. With this XML document: `<field> <html> <p>This</p><b>i</b>s it. </html> </field>` it produces: ` Thisis it.` but the wanted result (for limit of two words) is: `<field> <html> <p>This</p><b>i</b>s </html> </field>` So there are at least two problems: 1. Not counting words correctly; 2. Losing the markup. So, once again, your answer so far isn't what was meant and wanted -- please, consider providing a relevant answer, or deleting this one.

Comment: @Dimitre: That's not what was asked for. Read the comments again, the html is encoded as text with &lt;, they're not xml elements.

Comment: NP, but to be honest, I still think xslt/xpath isn't the best way of doing this, it's really not designed for text processing like this, unless of course this is part of a larger process.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Now that I see Dimitre's comments here, I'm really thinking that this would need some sort of parser because pseudoelement name will affect results. Otherwise, it should be point out all this assumptions: start and end tag marks, and entity references (particulary `&lt;`) are encoded, block style elements have explicit space (inside or next sibling) bettwen they and next word. Also, if it must keep the encode HTML, may be not valid.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Even if the problem is defined as you say ???, your code still produces wrong results. With this input: `<field>&lt;p&gt;Monday&lt;/p&gt;&lt;b&gt;T&lt;/b&gt;uesday</field>` the result is:

`&lt;p&gt;Monday&lt;/p&gt;&lt;b&gt;T&lt;/b&gt;uesday`

I guess the right result should be: `&lt;p&gt;Monday`

&lt;p&gt;Monday&lt;/p&gt;&lt;b&gt;T&lt;/b&gt;uesday

Comment: @Randy: I fully agree with @Flynn1179 that parsing unparsed HTML is not a task that is appropriate for XSLT (it *can* be done, but I and nobody with their right senses would do this with XSLT).

Comment: I totally agree it's by far a perfect solution, but it certainly produces the wanted output from the given input. @Dimitre, in that example it's doing exactly as it should: leaving the input unchanged if it has less than 30 words in it. Yeah, it'll probably be mis-counting words slightly in some cases, but a more 'perfect' solution is probably overkill for this purpose. @Randy only wanted to trim the field down to 30 words, not stick extra spaces where words are only separated by markup.

Comment: Incidentally, there is one fairly important flaw with this solution (that I'm surprised nobody else spotted): It leaves all remaining markup in after the 30 words, not just closing tags. For example, if you happen to have <b>something</b> as the 40th word or so, you'll end up with <b></b> in the output; not sure how much of an issue this is, but the text should still be correct.

Comment: I would love to be able to use something besides XSLT.  However, our CMS is based upon using XML and XSL.  Fortunately, the code should be pretty clean.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Flynn1179: No, I edited your code to get only one word. It is still outputting the two words -- not understanding that they are actually two words -- not one.

Comment: @Randy: If you must start with the unparsed XHTML text, then I would first unescape it and parse it, then I would apply XSLT on this parsed XML document. Any other solution with XSLT is too expensive and difficult to maintain -- it may be even difficult to prove that such solution really works.

Comment: @Flynn1179 - looks like the empty tags are a problem.  Do you have an idea of how to resolve this?

Comment: Not realistically without doing something horrifically complicated. If you can live with tags not being closed if they're still open after 30 words it's fairly easy to simply have it stop outputting ANYTHING at that point, but it would pretty much need to be able to parse XML otherwise. I'd strongly recommend using something other than XSLT to do this, or look into adding an extension function that your xslt can use, like this for C#: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=64

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

If you can clean your input so that you get a normalised string of the text you want to word count, you can compare the string-length of the string with spaces to the string-length of the string with spaces removed.  The difference should be your word count.

The word count function (template) will look something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="wordCount">
    <xsl:param name="input" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="'‒–—―'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="big"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($input, $sep, ' '))"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="small"><xsl:value-of select="translate($big, ' ', '')"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($big)-string-length($small)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The $sep parameter allows you to define a list of any character(s) (as well as white-space) that you want to count as a word separator.

You can then use a sequence constructor when you call the template to build the string you want (I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader):

```
<xsl:call-template name="wordCount">
    <xsl:with-param name="input">
        <!-- templates etc to output text from html -->
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```